# How to remove devtools Performance and ect tab in Electron?

Tags: javascript, debugging, vue.js, electron, devtools

How to remove devtools Performance and ect tab in Electron??

I want to remove some tab in electron devtools.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcncO.png)

Comment: You cannot, that's not customizable part.

Comment: I saw wechat mini program ide. the ide custom devtools. i am wondering how to...

Comment: if you build electron / or any chromium based framework by yourself and modify its code, it may possible. With prebuilt binaries, you can't.